# Trigger Handler class variables

Tags: apex, trigger

we follow the pattern Trigger-Trigger Handle. Inside the trigger handler we have a class vaibile of type RecordType that we define and instantiate immediately. I'll show you the code:

Trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {

    System.debug('****** Account trigger ***+'+ Trigger.isExecuting);
    AccountTriggerHandler handler = new AccountTriggerHandler(Trigger.isExecuting, Trigger.size);


    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore) {
        handler.OnBeforeInsert(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore) {
        handler.OnBeforeUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) {
        handler.OnAfterUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
    }


    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
        handler.OnAfterInsert(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
    }


}
```

Handler:

```
public without sharing class AccountTriggerHandler {
public RecordType accOfficineRT = UtilQuery.getRecordTypebyDevName('Enjoy_Officina','Account');
public void OnBeforeInsert(Account[] newAccount, Map<Id, Account> newAccountMap) {}
public void onAfterInsert(Account[] newAccount,  Map<Id, Account> newAccountMap) {}
public void OnBeforeUpdate(Account[] newAccount, Map<Id, Account> newAccountMap, Map<Id, Account> oldAccountMap) {}
public void OnAfterUpdate(Account[] newAccount, Map<Id, Account> newAccountMap, Map<Id, Account> oldAccountMap) {}

}
```

The query to retrieve the record type is done every time the trigger snaps an example in before and after update. There is a way to avoid this ?

Thanks for support

Comment: What do you do with this variable in your handler?

Comment: Are you using a SOQL query which you want to avoid? Why don't you use something like `Id accOfficineRT= Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Enjoy_Officina').getRecordTypeId();` ?

Comment: And consider making the trigger variable `static` so the describe call only runs once per transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting together the comments of others, and recommending that you use the recently introduced `getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName` (as the developer name never changes but the name can), and also adding lazy loading you get:

```
public ... class AccountTriggerHandler {

    private static Id officineRtId {
        get {
            if (officineRtId == null) {
                officineRtId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Enjoy_Officina').getRecordTypeId();
            }
            return officineRtId;
        }
        set;
    }

    ...
}
```

Why the lazy loading? Unlike other environments, `static` values only live for the duration of the transaction (request) so it is best to get into the habit of not initializing (expensive to initialize) `static` data by default. Using lazy loading means the value is initialized and cached when it is needed and otherwise no cost is incurred.